# How is the debug information organized and what does it contain?

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

How is the debug information organized in a compiled C/C++ program?
What does it contain?

How is the debug information used by the debugger, e.g. gdb, and how can I read the debug information better than nm or objdump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugging information depends on the operating system - `gdb` uses whatever the native format is.  On many UNIX-like systems, debugging information is stored in `DWARF` format.  You can use [`libdwarf` and `dwarfdump`](http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html) to examine this information.

EDIT: On Linux `readelf -w a.out` will print all `DWARF` debug info contained in the executable (also works for shared libraries and object files).

Comment: for microsoft compilers its generally in a pdb, one can use the DIA SDK to examine these(it ships with VS).